# Smooth function times continuous is Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lipschitz-functions, smooth-functions

Is a smooth compactly supported function multiplied by a continuous but not necessarily differentiable function already lipschitz continuous?

right now Im just interested in the answer. If you know something I would appreciate it if you could share it with me.

maybe there is a sufficient condition for uniform continuous functions to be Lipschitz?

Comment: If you consider the standard bump function $e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} $ and multiply it by $\sqrt{x}$, then I think you will probably find that this is not Lipschitz.

Comment: No, you can take a smooth function which is equal to $1$ on $[-1/2,1/2]$ and whatever you want outside, and multiply that by any continuous non-Lipschitz function you like.

Comment: @Stratossupportsthestrike "non[-locally]-Lipschitz?"  There are continuously differentiable functions that aren't Lipschitz, but none of those would work because they're locally Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes thank you, that's what I had in mind (more specifically, for the example I gave, it suffices that the function is not Lipschitz on $[-1/2,1/2]$)